# New to structures, I'm confused about how to return values out of a void function and put it into another function

Tags: c++, function, structure

my C++ class just started learning about developing structures. I'm stuck on a homework problem where I'm asked to write a program that uses a structure named movie_data and two movie_data variables to display information about a movie. I'm able to develop the movie_data structure correctly along with the two variable to outsoruce to a function named get_movie_info. However, because I set it as a void function, I'm unable to return anything produced by the get_movie_function to send to my movie_display function. I tried rewriting my functions to be of the movie_data structure data type, but that seemed to make things worse. The first function produces all the information correctly, but the second function doesn't output anything. Thank you for your time.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;


    struct movie_data
    {
        string title;
        string director;
        int year_released;
        int running_time;
    };

    //Function Prototype
    void get_movie_info(movie_data movie1, movie_data movie2);
    void movie_display(movie_data movie1, movie_data movie2);

int main()
{
    movie_data movie1;
    movie_data movie2;

    get_movie_info(movie1, movie2);
    movie_display(movie1, movie2);

    return 0;
}

    void get_movie_info(movie_data movie1, movie_data movie2)
{
    //Get movie_data's title
    cout << "Enter the title for the first movie: ";
    //cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, movie1.title);
    cout << movie1.title << endl;

    //Get movie_data's director
    cout << "Enter the director's name for " << movie1.title << ": ";
    //cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, movie1.director);
    cout << movie1.director << endl;

    //Get movie_data's release year
    cout << "Enter the release year for " << movie1.title << ": ";
    cin >> movie1.year_released;
    cout << movie1.year_released << endl;

    //Get movie_data's running time
    cout << "Enter the runtime of " << movie1.title << " in minutes: ";
    cin >> movie1.running_time;
    cout << movie1.running_time << " minutes" << endl;

    //Get movie_data's title
    cout << "Enter the title for the second movie: ";
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, movie2.title);
    cout << movie2.title << endl;

    //Get movie_data's director
    cout << "Enter the director's name for " << movie2.title << ": ";
    //cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, movie2.director);
    cout << movie2.director << endl;

    //Get movie_data's release year
    cout << "Enter the release year for " << movie2.title << ": ";
    cin >> movie2.year_released;
    cout << movie2.year_released << endl;

    //Get movie_data's running time
    cout << "Enter the runtime of " << movie2.title << " in minutes: ";
    cin >> movie2.running_time;
    cout << movie2.running_time << " minutes" << endl;

}

void movie_display(movie_data movie1, movie_data movie2)
{
    //Display movie1 information
    cout << "\nBelow is the data of the first movie:\n";
    cout << "Movie Title:  " << movie1.title << endl;
    cout << "Director's Name:  " << movie1.director << endl;
    cout << "Release Year:  " << movie1.year_released << endl;
    cout << "Movie Runtime in minutes:  " << movie1.running_time << endl;

    //Display the movie information
    cout << "\nBelow is the data of the second movie:\n";
    cout << "Movie Title:  " << movie2.title << endl;
    cout << "Director's Name:  " << movie2.director << endl;
    cout << "Release Year:  " << movie2.year_released << endl;
    cout << "Movie Runtime in minutes:  " << movie2.running_time << endl;
```

}

Comment: Use `ignore` carefully. `ignore` AFTER a read that leaves data in the stream that you want removed. Do not `ignore` before a future operation on the off chance that data was left in the stream because sooner or later you'll find yourself throwing out data you needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While @Kai's answer of using refrences would work and correctly would answer your original question, I suggest doing something else.

First, use a function to read in only one move_data and make it return that:

```
movie_data get_movie_info();
```

A possible implementation (using your code) could be like this:

```
movie_data get_movie_info(){
    movie_data movie; 

    cout << "Enter the title for the first movie: ";
    getline(cin, movie.title);

    cout << "Enter the director's name for " << movie.title << ": ";
    getline(cin, movie.director);

    cout << "Enter the release year for " << movie.title << ": ";
    cin >> movie.year_released;

    cout << "Enter the runtime of " << movie.title << " in minutes: ";
    cin >> movie.running_time;

    return movie;
}
```

Now you can call it twice to read your info and it will return the movie data as the correct structure.

```
movie_data movie1 = get_movie_data();
```

If you need to have structs that can be edited, references are a good choice. For returning multiple values, there are better choices: An array of a suitable size (std::array), a Pair for two, or a vector of Objects.

It's better to avoid having output parameters (as a rule of thumb, break it if you need to and know why) as they are hard to grasp from the signature and hard to keep track of.

Comment: Thank you, after taking your suggestions and messing around with the code, I was finally able to get it to work.

Comment: @PhantomDiclonius glad I could help you, playing around with a solution is the best way to improve and understand!

Answer (score 3):

Notice, that you do everything twice. The point of using functions, is to *not* do everything twice, so you should write one function to do one thing and just call it with different parameters. For example in `get_movie_info`. A better design would be to create a function that creates exactly one `movie_data` and returns it:

```
movie_data get_movie_info()
{
    movie_data result = {}; // That's the variable were we store the data

    //Get movie_data's title ...
    //Get movie_data's director ...
    //Get movie_data's release year ... 
    //Get movie_data's running time ...

    return result; // return the created movie data
}
```

The same goes for `movie_display`. Don't create a function that does exactly the same thing for two parameters, but create a function that does it one time and *call* it twice:

```
void movie_display(movie_data movie)
{
    cout << "Movie Title:  " << movie.title << endl;
    //And so on ...
}
```

Then you combine both in the `main` like this:

```
int main()
{
    movie_data movie1 = get_movie_info();
    movie_data movie2 = get_movie_info();

    std::cout << "data of the first movie:\n";
    movie_display(movie1);
    std::cout << "data of the second movie:\n";
    movie_display(movie2);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your function signatures to take references instead of values.

https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/72-passing-arguments-by-value/

```
void get_movie_info(movie_data& movie1, movie_data& movie2)
void movie_display(const movie_data& movie1, const movie_data& movie2)
```

Comment: Sidenote: This applies to anything you want updated inside a function, even pointers.